# opening a file with an accented character in its name, in Python 2 on Windows

Tags: windows, unicode, filenames, python-2.x

In a directory in Windows I have 2 files, both of them with an accented character in its name: `t1û.fn` and `t2ű.fn`; The `dir` command in the Command Prompt shows both correctly:

```
S:\p>dir t*.fn
 Volume in drive S is q
 Volume Serial Number is 05A0-8823

 Directory of S:\p

2017-09-03  14:54                 4 t1û.fn
2017-09-03  14:54                 4 t2ű.fn
               2 File(s)              8 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  19,110,621,184 bytes free
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of dir]

However, Python can't see both files:

```
S:\p>python -c "import os; print [(fn, os.path.isfile(fn)) for fn in os.listdir('.') if fn.endswith('.fn')]"
[('t1\xfb.fn', True), ('t2u.fn', False)]
```

It looks like Python 2 uses a single-byte API for filenames, thus the accented character in t1û.fn is mapped to the single byte `\xfb`, and the accented character in t2ű.fn is mapped to the unaccented ASCII single byte `u`.

How is it possible to use a multi-byte API for filenames on Windows in Python 2? I want to open both files in the console version of Python 2 on Windows.

Comment: FYI, in case you make the jump to Python 3, note that `bytes` paths were deprecated on Windows because of this behavior. Support for `bytes` paths returned in 3.6+ by pretending the filesystem encoding is UTF-8. In 3.6 you can open `b't1\xc3\xbb.fn'` in addition to `"t1û.fn"`, and `os.listdir(b'.')` encodes filenames as UTF-8. Internally it transcodes to UTF-16 to use the Windows wide-character API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a unicode string:

```
f1 = open(u"t1\u00fb.fn")     # t1û.fn
f2 = open(u"t2\u0171.fn")     # t2ű.fn
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for `open`. Also `os.listdir(u'.')` returns the filenames with the right accented characters.