# running a cmd file with an accented character in its name, in Python 2 on Windows

Tags: windows, unicode, python-2.x, popen

I have the file `t2ű.cmd` on Windows with an accented character in its name, and I'd like to run it from Python 2 code.

Opening the file (`open(u't2\u0170.cmd')`) works if I pass the filename as a `unicode` literal, but no `str` literal works, because `\u0170` is not on the code page of Windows. (See this question for more on opening files with accented characters in their name: [opening a file with an accented character in its name, in Python 2 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46025407/97248).)

Running the file from the Command Prompt without Python works.

I tried passing an `str` literal to `os.system`, `os.popen`, `os.spawnl` and `subprocess.call` (both with and without the shell), but it wasn't able to find the file.

These don't work, they raise *UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u170'...*:

- `os.system(u't2\u170.cmd')`
- `os.popen(u't2\u170.cmd')`
- `os.spawnl(u't2\u170.cmd', u't2')`
- `subprocess.call(u't2\u170.cmd')`
- `subprocess.call(u'"t2\u170.cmd"')`
- `subprocess.call([u't2\u170.cmd'])`

In this project it's not feasible to upgrade to Python 3.

It's not feasible to rename the file, because these files can have arbitrary (user-supplied) names on a read-only share, and also the directory name can contain accented characters.

In C I would use any of the `wsystem`, `wpopen` or `wspawnl` functions in `<process.h>`.

Preferably I'm looking for a solution which works with the standard Python modules (no need to install packages). But I'm interested in any solution.

I need a solution which doesn't open a new window.

Eventually I want to pass command-line arguments to program, and the arguments will contain arbitrary Unicode characters.

Comment: Try using `os.startfile` instead, looking at the Python source code (2.7.14rc1) it looks to me as if this supports Unicode strings.  Failing that, I guess you could use ctypes to call CreateProcessW explicitly.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, that may suffice since it looks like pts doesn't need command-line arguments. Note also that `os.startfile` won't wait to get the exit code, and it will create a new console that will be destroyed as soon as the batch script exits. Otherwise the options are either to use ctypes (as you said) or create an extension module. PyWin32's `win32process` module is of no use here since it also calls `CreateProcessA` in Python 2.

Comment: Thank you for the clarificions on `os.startfile`, `win32process` and `CreateProcessW`. It looks like there is nothing readily available (other than manual coding with `ctypes`) which calls `CreateProcessW` in Python 2. If you write an answer about this, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the comment by @eryksun.

We need to call the system call `CreateProcessW` or the C functions `wspawnl`, `wsystem` or `wpopen`. Python 2 doesn't have anything built in which would call any of these functions. Writing an extension module in C or calling the functions using `ctypes` could be a solution.

The C functions `CreateProcessA`, `spawnl`, `system` and `popen` don't work.

Answer (score -1):

As described in the [pep 0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), if you want to use unicode characters in a python script, just add a `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your script (it's ok after the she-bang):

```
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

os.system('t2ű.cmd')
```

If you still find problems, you may take a look on some packages, like [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

It should work now directly, with no escaping code.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Your suggestion doesn't work, with it I still get this error: *UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u170'...*. Equivalently, it doesn't work with `os.system(u't2\u0170.cmd'.encode('utf-8'))` either. Please note that creating the U+0170 character in Python is not my problem, I know how to do it, and it works. My problem is outlined in the question.

Comment: I think the problem lays in the fact that you are trying to put escape codes inside the unicode strings still after the encoding declaration. Take a look at the official [guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

Comment: Also have you tried alternative routes, like `os.system(u't2\u0170'.encode("<encoding>"))` where you can find `<encoding>` through a `>>>sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: I've just checked the Python 2 source code, and as far as I can see os.system() only ever calls the ASCII version of CreateProcess, so unless you can encode the string in the current code page I think you're out of luck.  It isn't clear to me whether or not `sys.stdout.encoding` (the encoding of the terminal) is always the same as the current code page.

Comment: @oldMammuth: I'm sure I'm using Unicode escapes correctly: `open(u't2\u0170.cmd').read()` returns the file's contents correctly. However, none of `os.system(u't2\u0170.cmd')`, `os.system(u't2\u0170.cmd'.encode('utf-8'))` or any other encoding works, because U+0170 is not part of the current code page. I need a solution where I don't have to change code pages, because I want to be able to run scripts with arbitrary names.

Comment: @oldMammuth: *you are trying to put escape codes inside the unicode strings still after the encoding declaration.* This shouldn't be a problem, it should work as intended. I've retried with literals (no escapes), with and without `u`, nothing worked. Your proposed solution doesn't work either, it's not able to find a program with that name.

Comment: @pts have you looked into issue [1602](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602) and the package [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console)? I'm sorry to link a package I never used, but in Italian we are much luckier, so apart from declaring the unicode encoding I never had much trouble with windows filenames...

Comment: @oldMammuth: Thank you for mentioning *win-unicode-console*, it's a useful package. However, I fail to see its relevance here: my problem is not with creating Unicode strings or displaying them on the console. My problem in this question is running an external program with a Unicode character in its name.